# preventing spaces in a string input c++

Tags: validation, visual-c++, input

I'm working on a project where I'm inputting strings for things like names and passwords. I'm trying to fool proof it by adding an input validation that tells the user to only input in one word. The problem is I'm not sure how make this kind of input validation Here's kind of an example of what the input would look like

```
int main(){
   string firstname, lastname, password;
    cout<<"Enter in your first name:"<<endl;
    cin>>firstname;
    cout<<"Now Enter your last name:"<<endl;
    cin>>lastname;
    cout<<"Lastly enter a password"<<endl;
    cin>>password


    return 0;



}
```

Now I really want input validation for the password variable so a user won't try to make a password that is two words or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you do not want the password to have any spaces. So, search for a space in the password; if found, ask to re-enter.

```
if (password.find (' ') != string::npos) 
{
    cout  << "Password cannot have spaces!" << endl; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the characters in `password` and check whether any one of them is a space. If you find a space (or any other invalid character) reject the password.

```
BOOL is_valid = TRUE;
for(std::string::iterator chr = password.begin(); chr != password.end(); ++chr) 
{
    if (*chr == ' ')
       // add more conditions here if you'd like..
    {
        // invalidate the password
        is_valid = FALSE;
        break;
    }   
}

if(!is_valid)
{
    // handle the case when the password is not valid..
}
```

The above is nice because it gives you the chance to inspect each character and check multiple rules at each step, but if you're really only looking to find whether `password` contains a space then you could use [the `find` method](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/):

```
BOOL is_valid = (str.find(' ') == std::string::npos);
```